# Django 1.11. How to get date to update itself daily

Tags: django

I would like for the date to update itself daily. Here I named it today's date. It will later be used in subtraction to get the difference btwn today and a "book_before" date. For example:
booked_before is 2018-11-27
today_date is 2018-11-14
so delta.days will be 13 days.
tomorrow is will be 12 days..the day after 11 days..and so on

**Models.py**

```
class JoinedSafaris(models.Model):

    book_before=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    today_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


    def datediff(self):
        date1 = self.today_date
        date2 = self.book_before
        delta= date2 - date1
        return delta.days
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need today's date to calculate the delta, then you don't need a field for that:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class JoinedSafaris(models.Model):

    book_before=models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def datediff(self):
        delta = self.book_before - timezone.now().date()
        return delta.days
```

Comment: Its at night here in Kenya, like 40 mins to midnight. I'll know if it works then..Thanks for reaching out...

Comment: Above answer solves the problem. In diff more complicated situations, you can write cron jobs using celery that runs everyday.